# How do I make Javascript wait for one function to finish before moving to another?

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and I need help with making my code wait for functions to finish before moving on to the next. In my code, I'm sending an email using SES, and I'm publishing a topic within SNS.

After sending the email and publishing the topic, I need to navigate the user to a thank you page.

With how I have my code setup, it's very inconsistent. Sometimes it will send the the email and publish before navigating, and sometimes it will do one or the other then navigate. I need help with understanding how to make the code wait for those two functions to finish before navigating to a different page.

Thank you all in advance!

I've tried using an if statement, but it didn't work out as I thought.

```
sns.publish(snsParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
ses.sendEmail(sesParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
window.location = 'https://abc123.com/contact/thanks/';
```

Comment: You need to read about callbacks and asynchronous calls.  Further, you can solve this using async functions and Promises.

Comment: Check the link above, looks not related but the accepted answer would also solve your problem

Comment: just use the async await syntax its cleaner https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Thank you @CristianTraìna. I'm looking into that answer.

Comment: @Ele I'm looking into callbacks and asynchronous calls now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that either by using the second call as a callback to the first one or by promisifying the calls:

```
sns.publish(snsParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
}).promise().then(() => {
    return ses.sendEmail(sesParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
}).promise().then(() => window.location = 'https://abc123.com/contact/thanks/'));
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Promise.all` be better? You can also omit the callback if you're using Promises, if you want, it doesn't serve much purpose

Comment: @CertainPerformance if you want to redirect only after both actions took place successfully and you don't care about the order in which the actions were executed you can indeed use `Promise.all`. All that said, I wouldn't do things like sns/ses actions from the frontend - better call your backend and do it there!

Comment: @alfasin I tried this out, but it doesn't work. After publishing, it navigates directly to the new page. It doesn't send the email from SES. Any ideas? Also, I don't care what order the two functions are executed in, so I think I will look into Promise.all.